# php foreach add += string in a variable return 0

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

i have created this code

```
       $cities = arrary('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5');

       $query = "SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE ";

        foreach($cities as $city){

           $query += " AND city = '$city' ";

        }

        echo $query;
```

This code print zero

i want to make the $query output like this

```
  SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE city = 'city1' AND city = 'city2' .... etc.
```

Comment: I believe `PHP` uses a period `.` as a concat operator....NB I know almost nothing about PHP.

Comment: i'm really sorry i just was stupid becuase i've worked about 14 hours and my mind is exploded

Comment: try using [implode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) on `$cities`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$cities = array('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5');

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE ";

    foreach($cities as $key => $city){
      if($key ==0){
        $query .= " city = '$city' ";
       }
       else{
       $query .= " AND city = '$city' ";
       }
    }

    echo $query;
```

Comment: How can city equals to `city1` **AND** `city2` ?

Comment: I mean that the generated string will be `SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE city = 'city1' AND city = 'city2'`. And I don't think that `city = 'city1' AND city = 'city2'` could be possible. But with `OR` it's better.

Comment: but the question was specific for 'and' not for 'or'

Answer (score 3):

```php
   $cities = array('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5');

   $query = "SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE city='"
          .implode("' AND city='", $cities)."'";

   echo $query;
```

but this query always return empty result, if different cities in array,
maybe your need select query look like:

```php
$cities = array('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM data_entry '
    .'WHERE city IN("'.implode('","',$cities).'")';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE 1=1";
foreach($cities as $city){
    $query .= " AND city = '$city' ";
}
```

Don't forget to escape the `$city` values in order to avoid security issues... (SQL injections)

Comment: Don't worry everything is escaped with PDO prepared statements

Comment: `AND` will not work because no string can be `city1` and at the same time `city2`.

Comment: if you're using PDO, then instead of " AND city = '$city' "; consider using " OR city = ?"; and pass the array

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
$cities=array('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5');
$query="SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE city='".$cities[0]."'";
foreach(array_slice($cities,1) as $city)
{
    $query.=" OR city='$city'";
}
echo $query;
```

Or, from the idea of didierc:

```
$cities=array('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5');
$query="SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE city='".$cities[0].implode("' OR city='",array_slice($cities,1))."'";
echo $query;
```